# I want to create an array of labels and sort them according to the values in the labels using insertion sort

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, simulator

I am taking input from 5 textboxes and sorting the values inserted into the text boxes by putting them into labels and moving the labels around till the values in them are sorted.

I have so far put them into labels, but I don't know how to move he labels on button click and let the labels move to get sorted.

This is one way of simulating the algorithm of insertion sort.

my code so far for button click :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "insertion sort")
    {  
        for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (c != 0)
            {
                myLabel[i].Dispose();
            }

            myLabel[i] = new Label();
            myLabel[i].Location = new Point(a, b);
            myLabel[i].Width = 70;
            myLabel[i].Height = 70;
            myLabel[i].BackColor=Color.White;
            myLabel[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel[i]);
            a = a + 100;
            myLabel[i].Visible = true;
        }

        timer1.Start();
        c++;
    }

    myLabel[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
    myLabel[1].Text = textBox5.Text;
    myLabel[2].Text = textBox4.Text;
    myLabel[3].Text = textBox3.Text;
    myLabel[4].Text = textBox2.Text;
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{   
    Label[] myLabel=new Label[5];
    int a = 30;         //x coordinates of first label in label1 array
    int b = 125;        //y coordinates of first label in label1 array
    int c = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int i;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Selection Sort");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Insertion Sort");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to sort value of textbox and then put value in labels. Something like this :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "insertion sort")
        {  
            for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (c != 0)
                {
                    myLabel[i].Dispose();
                }

                myLabel[i] = new Label();
                myLabel[i].Location = new Point(a, b);
                myLabel[i].Width = 70;
                myLabel[i].Height = 70;
                myLabel[i].BackColor=Color.White;
                myLabel[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel[i]);
                a = a + 100;
                myLabel[i].Visible = true;
            }

            timer1.Start();
            c++;
        }

                var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Text.Value));
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(textBox2.Text, textBox2.Text.Value));
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(textBox3.Text, textBox3.Text.Value));
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(textBox4.Text, textBox4.Text.Value));
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(textBox5.Text, textBox5.Text.Value));
                list.Sort(Compare2);
                int increment = 0;
                foreach(var item in list)
                {                
                    myLabel[increment].Text=item.Value;
                    increment++;
                }           
    }



static int Compare2(KeyValuePair<string, string> a, KeyValuePair<string, string> b)
        {
            return a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value);
        }
```

Comment: are u using a listbox hear can't we do it using timers  ? also i want to show the labels moving to sort the numbers inside them